# How do i get documents from document library Programatically

Tags: document-library

I need all the documents from the Document library.

Answer (score 0):

You would loop through the library like a normal SPList and then cast the file to a SPFile type

```
foreach (SPListItem i in currentList.Items)
{
    SPFile fi = currentList.GetItemById(i.ID).File;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are folders present in the library containing the files and the requirement is to get those files as well, then recursive scope can be defined in `SPQuery`. Example:

```
SPList oList = oWebsite.Lists["Shared Documents"];
SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
oQuery.Query = strQuery;
oQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\""; 
SPListItemCollection collItemsRoot = oList.GetItems(oQuery);

foreach (SPListItem oItem in collItemsRoot)
{
    if (oItem.FileSystemObjectType == SPFileSystemObjectType.File)
    {
        string fileName = oItem.File.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is strQuery in 2nd answer

Comment: strQuery will be your Caml query...